# 複数条件でのcrontabの書き方

Tags: centos, bash, sh, cron

毎月１日２時５分に特別な処理を行い、
１日を除く毎週月曜日1時5分に定期的な処理をするスクリプトを実行させたい思い、
crontabに下記のように書いてcronを実行しました。

```
5 1 2-31 * mon root sh /hoge/hoge/hoge.sh
5 2 1 * * root sh /hoge/hoge/hoge.sh
```

1日を除く月曜日の時は、上の行のみが実行されて、
1日の時は、下の行のみが実行されると思います。
1日で月曜日の時も下の行のみが実行されると思います。
crontabは、上記のような書き方であっていますでしょうか。
また、crontabで複数条件が評価される場合は、どのような順番で評価されるのでしょうか。

自作したスクリプトは、

```
if [ 実行時の日付が1日であるか ]
   特別な処理
else
   定期的な処理
fi
```

として、スクリプト内のif文で処理を振り分けています。
使用しているOSはCentOS7です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
5 1 2-31 * mon root sh /hoge/hoge/hoge.sh
```

こちらの条件は「１日以外の全ての月曜日」という条件ではなく、「１日以外もしくは、月曜日」という条件であると解釈されます。

ですので、個人的には、以下のように記述するのが良いのではないかと思います。

```
5 2 1 * *   root sh /hoge/hoge/special.sh
# crontab のコマンド部分において、 % だけは特殊処理されてしまうので、\ でエスケープ。
# 詳細は man 5 crontab を参照。
5 1 * * mon root [ $(date +\%d) -ne 1 ] && sh /hoge/hoge/normal.sh
```

これにより、日付ごとの振り分け処理が crontab のみを確認すれば良くなります。

参考: https://superuser.com/q/348348/485243

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。crontabの条件はandだと思っており、うまくいかなく困っておりました。教えていただいた方法でシェルを切り分けて、行ってみます。ありがとうございました。